# letters in a word are displayed properly in IE7 and not in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie to my project. Here we use Javascript,CSS and HTML to display web page. I am not at all familiar with all these. In IE8, letters in a word are displaying vertically but the same code works in IE7.

It should appear as "Channel Preference" and not as
c
               h
a
n
n
e
l

p
r
e
f
r
e
n
c
e

CSS parameters are as follows ::

```
.SubjectAreaChoiceAnchor, .SubjectAreaChoiceAnchor:link, .SubjectAreaChoiceAnchor:visited  
{  
   font: normal 11px Tahoma;  
   color: #000000;  
   padding: 2px 2px 2px 29px;  
    display: block;  
    cursor: default;  
    white-space: nowrap;  
    text-decoration: none;  
} 

.SubjectAreaChoiceAnchor:hover  
{  
    color: black;  
    background-color: #D1DDE7;  
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 29px;  
    border-top: solid 1px white;  
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;  
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  
}
```

HTML Looks like this::

```
<  div class="dialogBody" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">  
<  div style="display: block;" id="idExtTagSelector">  
 <  table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
   <  a onclick="WebExpressionSelector.onChoose('idExtTagSelector','channelPref','','true','Channel Preference'); return false;" href="javascript:void(null)" displayname="Channel Preference" usequotes="true" defaultvalue="" name="channelPref" eid="idExtTagSelector" class="SubjectAreaChoiceAnchor" id="idWebExprchannelPref">Channel Preference
<  /a>  
<  /table><  /div><  /div>
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.
Prathima

Comment: Your html code has some problems, a table needs to have at least a  <tr> and <td> inside each other.

Comment: Also I don't see ABC anywhere on your code, could you provide the real example you want to correct please?

Comment: but the same code works in IE7 without giving <td> and <tr> 's

Comment: Probably your table/tr/td has a little width and IE is trying to let all the text being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned your HTML table isn't formatted correctly. The correct way for you to have a table should be as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your case, if you must use a table to get all the values next to each other the table should be as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You should also only really use tables for tabular data. Anything else should be styles via the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you have to type your html correctly, expecially closing tags, and the table structure needs at least a `<tr>` and `<td>` inside. Then you can see if the problem persist and we can try to find a solution.

```
<div class="dialogBody" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">  
    <div style="display: block;" id="idExtTagSelector">  
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                   <a onclick="WebExpressionSelector.onChoose('idExtTagSelector','channelPref','','true','Channel Preference'); return false;" href="javascript:void(null)" displayname="Channel Preference" usequotes="true" defaultvalue="" name="channelPref" eid="idExtTagSelector" class="SubjectAreaChoiceAnchor" id="idWebExprchannelPref">Channel Preference
                    </a>
                 </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```